# splitting Django monolithic

Tags: django, microservices, monolithic

Let's say I've a big Django monolithic e-commerce
I've product, orders and webhooks apps

I want to split them to make sure that when a service is down, the others stays up

when I do some changes in a model, I don't want to keep redoing the changes in the others
any ideas on better approaches?

Comment: You will share the same database across services right? Then database migration will reflect in all services as long as they use the same source code. That includes migration files.

Comment: exactly, my issue is with code, changing the model in one will require changes in the other, they're not decoupled at all

Comment: my thoughts are just to do a horizontal scale and move on